# Keeping track of sessions attended for one to one program "package"

Tags: wordpress

I do one-to-one consultations with clients and have a wellness "package" where a client can buy few consults/ massage treatments as a package to save money. This is not a group situation. So what is the best way to store that information and keep track of how many sessions this person has used and what kind? consult? massage? how many? If there are many packages sold to different clients, will they be different campaigns for different persons? or events? dates are not typically fixed in advance but are set up as we go. Also if a person buys another package at a different time, how do I store this information? 
Thanks in advance for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

You could create activity types for Packages & Consultations. When a package is purchased create an activity in the contact record. As they use their consultations record them as activities. You can then run Activity reports (or search) filtered on those activity types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good answer - but @neerja someone might perhaps be able to provide a better one if you update your question to explain how you sell packages through CiviCRM.  Are you using a contribution page? Events? Something else? What CMS (Drupal, WordPress, etc.) are you using?

Comment: thank you. I am still new. Using it on wordpress. I have started using activities for first consult, followup and treatments separately but have not been clear how to do packages and keep track of activities within a package

Answer (score 0):

I would go down the Activity route but consider doing a single Activity for the 'package' with a custom field to record how many treatments, and another field that you would update each time they have a treatment

If you were then using Drupal I could see a way that you could use a webform (from a link in a view display) that would allow you to just 'click a button' so that you increment the 'number used' by one (thinking the webform 'calc' field but it may be called something else, but i recall we helped get this working with civi components in webform)

Comment: thank you. I am still new. Using it on wordpress. I have started using activities for first consult, followup and treatments separately but have not been clear how to do packages and keep track of activities within a package. Not used webforms yet.

Comment: Webforms is only Drupal. For packages, then I think my first suggestion is one option to further investigate